# Is flatMap an efficient way to add elements to a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

For example, see the following function which duplicates even numbers in a stream:

```
Stream<Integer> duplicateEvens(Stream<Integer> items) {
    return items.flatMap(i -> {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            return Stream.of(i, i);
        } else {
            return Stream.of(i);
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative approach could be to use a stream builder as follows:

```
Stream<Integer> duplicateEvens(Stream<Integer> items) {
Stream.Builder result = builder();
Stream<Integer> extra = items.peek(result.add(i))
.filter(i -> i%2 == 0);
return Stream.concat(result.build(), extra);
}
```

Comment: It’s the *only* way, so there’s no alternative to compare efficiency.

Comment: Could use a steam builder, I updated the question to show an example of this

Comment: No, even when you fix all compiler errors of that builder code, it will not work.

Comment: Note that the documentation says that `peek` should only be used for debugging purposes.